# Getting Attribute Value in JS - Fastest Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I have an attribute called "data-price". Does anyone know how I can access this attributes value using this similar syntax:

**Ideal Syntax**

```
div[0].id: 48ms // this seems to be the fastest approach
```

**Alternate Syntax - Slower Performance**

```
div.attr('id'): 1545ms // slowest
div[0].getAttribute('id'): 74ms
```

See Attr() Performance Methods
http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/10/jquery-attrid-vs-0id-performance.html

Comment: I was like 'how does `div.attr('id')` take 1.5 seconds` before realizing it was a million operations. Anyways, the test in the link can be considered quite moot for various reasons, see https://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/bulletproof-javascript-benchmarks/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
thing.getAttribute('data-price')
thing.dataset.price
$(thing).data('price')
```

Take your pick.

Comment: Thank you. .data() seems to be slow when compared to getAttribute(). Is it not possible to access data-price using similar syntax `div[0].id`?

Comment: `this.dataset.price` is the closest example to `div[0].id`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset  Make sure to note the browser coverage though